# Bloomberg Data Pull in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

Can I pull the CACS (corporate actions) of a security from Bloomberg with its Bloomberg Unique ID in Excel using a '=BDS()' formula? 
I can't seem to be able to do this.

In a different circumstance I was using a formula to pull a single field with this '=BDP($A$3&" Cusip",B3)' and I was able to use that.

However, I cant seem to be able to pull the CACS information using BDS in a similar way.

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should fetch the history of corporate actions as seen on the DVD page, which is a subset of CACS - it will contain dividends, splits, spinoffs, etc. :

```
=BDS(ticker, "DVD_HIST_ALL")
```

I don't think there is a way to pull the whole content of CACS but you can ask HELP HELP if they know a way.

Answer (score 1):

Only sub-sets of the CACS data are available, not the whole screen that you see in the terminal. I imagine this is because the different types of entry in CACS have different data schemas, so would be hard to handle all the possibilities with one BDS() call.

Get your security, equity, whatever in the Bloomi Terminal, and type FLDS , then use the search panel . This will show you the field names that might have the "Bulk Data" you want for the BDS() function.

eg
"AAPL US Eqty FLDS Go"
and type "dividend" or "split" in the search field. If you click on the right on any fields with "Show Bulk Data..." you can see what is in them, use that "Mnemonic" in your BDS() call.

To be honest, my experience of BDS() has been pretty trial & error, especially decoding what is in each of the returned columns.

Answer (score 0):

- Goto MA function in BB
- get your action id or corporate id for your merger
- goto your api code editor and input
- ticker -> ["[Action Id] Action"]

  field  ->  "tickers"

this is assuming "refdata". you can have multiple action ids

for excel the format is the same. input "[action id]" + " Action" without brackets in the str

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).